# Why the Android emu crashes?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation

I have an exercise to make a "Find the number" game. One person insert a number that disappear and a second person insert numbers and gets Cold\Warm hints till he find the first person's number and get a message that reveal the number (in case second person didn't pay attention...).

My problem is that I don't get error in Eclipse and the Android emulator crashes.

Here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtNum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtFriend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFind"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Guess the Number" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the class code (I try to make the code as simple as I can).

```
public class ActivityPesah3 extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pesah3);

    final EditText txtNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNum);
    final EditText txtFriend = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFriend);      
    Button btnFind = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
    final TextView txtTry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTry);

    btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int a = Integer.valueOf(txtNum.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.valueOf(txtFriend.getText().toString());                
            txtNum.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (b == a+25 || a== a-25) {
                txtTry.setText("Cold");
            }else if(b == a+10 || b== a-10){
                txtTry.setText("Hot");
            }else if(b==a){
                txtTry.setText("Your friend number is: " + b);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: If it crashes, always add the stacktrace with your question please.

Comment: `</LinearLayout>` <--Does this have an opening tag?

Comment: Describe exactly what you mean - does the *emulator* itself crash, or does the *program* you are developing?

Comment: The xml is complete, but for some reason the opening layout don't appear in the gray part of the code. The problem occur when I insert the first person number and click the button. I get an Unfortunately message in the emulator and then the program crashes.

Comment: @user3395989 Of course it crashes. You get NumberFormatException trying to get int from the value that haven't entered yet. You should check entered values whether those are numbers or not.

Comment: What do you mean? Where is the problem in the code? I'm kinda new in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of the problem, it seems you're getting an unhandled `NumberFormatException`. This is happening because you are trying to call `Integer.valueOf()` on an empty String. One way to avoid this is to surround the offending code with a `try-catch`.

```
btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {
                int a = Integer.valueOf(txtNum.getText().toString());
                int b = Integer.valueOf(txtFriend.getText().toString());                
                txtNum.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (b == a + 25 || a == a - 25)
                {
                    txtTry.setText("Cold");
                }
                else if (b == a + 10 || b == a - 10)
                {
                    txtTry.setText("Hot");
                }
                else if (b == a)
                {
                    txtTry.setText("Your friend number is: " + b);
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                txtTry.setText("Invalid input.");
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Also, you should take some time and learn to read your LogCat. It will save you a lot of time. In this case, it would have told you not only what the Exception is, but the exact line number it's occurring on as well.

Comment: OK, it's stop crashing with your example, but the game itself doesn't quite work. If I insert the first number and click the button, it give me the "Invalid input" message, and to make the number disappear I have to try and insert a second number in a the "Guess number" EditText. From there, if I try to guess the first person's number it won't give me any message, only if I type the correct number and then I get the last part of the IF. In short, why only the last part of the IF works?

Comment: Well, that's a separate question, but I'll help if you can exactly explain what the desired flow of your program is. A first guess, though, judging from "Hot" & "Cold" , is that you're trying to decide how close a number is to another. Instead of testing for equality, i.e. `==`, you should be using comparison operators: `<` & `>`.

Comment: Thank you! With your help it now works perfectly, although there are a few things in the code I'm not fully understand yet but I'll keep learning.

Comment: Sure, but how? Do I need to create an account? I signed in via FB so I can't use some features...